# Got exception "unread block data" when reading Hbase table to Spark(1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82) RDD using PySpark on Yarn-Client on HDP (2.2) plantform

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, block, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a strange exception when reading Hbase (0.98.4.2.2.0.0) table to Spark (1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82) RDD using PySpark on Yarn-Client(2.6.0) on HDP(2.2) plantform:

```
2015-04-14 19:05:11,295 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(71)) - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, hadoop-node05.mathartsys.com): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2421)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1382)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I followed the Spark example Python code:（https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py）
and my code is :

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="HBaseInputFormat")

    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com,hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com,hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com",
            "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "test",
            "hbase.cluster.distributed":"true",
            "hbase.rootdir":"hdfs://hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com:8020/apps/hbase/data",
            "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort":"2181",
            "zookeeper.session.timeout":"30000",
            "zookeeper.znode.parent":"/hbase-unsecure"}
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

    hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf)
    output = hbase_rdd.collect()
    for (k, v) in output:
        print (k, v)

    sc.stop()
```

and submitted the job like this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --driver-class-path /opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/* hbase_inputformat.py
```

My environment is:

> Centos 6.5
>   HDP 2.2
>   Spark 1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041

Can give some suggestion to solve it?!

The full log is:

```
[root@hadoop-node03 hbase]# spark-submit --master yarn-client --driver-class-path /opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/* hbase_test2.py 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. 
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 
2015-04-14 22:41:34,839 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Changing view acls to: root 
2015-04-14 22:41:34,846 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Changing modify acls to: root 
2015-04-14 22:41:34,847 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root) 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,459 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] slf4j.Slf4jLogger (Slf4jLogger.scala:applyOrElse(80)) - Slf4jLogger started 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,524 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] Remoting (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Starting remoting 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,754 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] Remoting (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:44295] 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,764 INFO  [Thread-2] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 44295. 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,790 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering MapOutputTracker 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,806 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering BlockManagerMaster 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,826 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.DiskBlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20150414224135-a290 
2015-04-14 22:41:35,832 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - MemoryStore started with capacity 265.4 MB 
2015-04-14 22:41:36,535 WARN  [Thread-2] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
2015-04-14 22:41:36,823 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.HttpFileServer (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-b963d482-e9be-476b-85b0-94ab6cd8076c 
2015-04-14 22:41:36,830 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.HttpServer (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting HTTP Server 
2015-04-14 22:41:36,902 INFO  [Thread-2] server.Server (Server.java:doStart(272)) - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT 
2015-04-14 22:41:36,921 INFO  [Thread-2] server.AbstractConnector (AbstractConnector.java:doStart(338)) - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:58608 
2015-04-14 22:41:36,925 INFO  [Thread-2] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 58608. 
2015-04-14 22:41:37,054 INFO  [Thread-2] server.Server (Server.java:doStart(272)) - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT 
2015-04-14 22:41:37,069 INFO  [Thread-2] server.AbstractConnector (AbstractConnector.java:doStart(338)) - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040 
2015-04-14 22:41:37,070 INFO  [Thread-2] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040. 
2015-04-14 22:41:37,073 INFO  [Thread-2] ui.SparkUI (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Started SparkUI at http://hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:4040
2015-04-14 22:41:38,034 INFO  [Thread-2] impl.TimelineClientImpl (TimelineClientImpl.java:serviceInit(285)) - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-04-14 22:41:38,220 INFO  [Thread-2] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com/10.0.0.222:8050 
2015-04-14 22:41:38,511 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Requesting a new application from cluster with 3 NodeManagers 
2015-04-14 22:41:38,536 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (15360 MB per container) 
2015-04-14 22:41:38,537 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead 
2015-04-14 22:41:38,537 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Setting up container launch context for our AM 
2015-04-14 22:41:38,544 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Preparing resources for our AM container 
2015-04-14 22:41:39,125 WARN  [Thread-2] shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory (DomainSocketFactory.java:<init>(116)) - The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded. 
2015-04-14 22:41:39,207 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Uploading resource file:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar -> hdfs://hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1428915066363_0013/spark-assembly-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,428 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Uploading resource file:/root/hbase/hbase_test2.py -> hdfs://hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1428915066363_0013/hbase_test2.py 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,511 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Setting up the launch environment for our AM container 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,564 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Changing view acls to: root 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,564 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Changing modify acls to: root 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,565 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root) 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,568 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Submitting application 13 to ResourceManager 
2015-04-14 22:41:40,609 INFO  [Thread-2] impl.YarnClientImpl (YarnClientImpl.java:submitApplication(251)) - Submitted application application_1428915066363_0013 
2015-04-14 22:41:41,615 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application report for application_1428915066363_0013 (state: ACCEPTED) 
2015-04-14 22:41:41,621 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - 
         client token: N/A 
         diagnostics: N/A 
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A 
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1 
         queue: default 
         start time: 1429022500586 
         final status: UNDEFINED 
         tracking URL: http://hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:8088/proxy/application_1428915066363_0013/
         user: root 
2015-04-14 22:41:42,624 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application report for application_1428915066363_0013 (state: ACCEPTED) 
2015-04-14 22:41:43,627 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application report for application_1428915066363_0013 (state: ACCEPTED) 
2015-04-14 22:41:44,631 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application report for application_1428915066363_0013 (state: ACCEPTED) 
2015-04-14 22:41:45,635 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application report for application_1428915066363_0013 (state: ACCEPTED) 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,278 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - ApplicationMaster registered as Actor[akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@hadoop-node05.mathartsys.com:42992/user/YarnAM#708767775] 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,284 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:8088/proxy/application_1428915066363_0013), /proxy/application_1428915066363_0013 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,287 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ui.JettyUtils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,638 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application report for application_1428915066363_0013 (state: RUNNING) 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,639 INFO  [Thread-2] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - 
         client token: N/A 
         diagnostics: N/A 
         ApplicationMaster host: hadoop-node05.mathartsys.com 
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0 
         queue: default 
         start time: 1429022500586 
         final status: UNDEFINED 
         tracking URL: http://hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:8088/proxy/application_1428915066363_0013/
         user: root 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,641 INFO  [Thread-2] cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Application application_1428915066363_0013 has started running. 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,795 INFO  [Thread-2] netty.NettyBlockTransferService (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Server created on 56053 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,797 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Trying to register BlockManager 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,800 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] storage.BlockManagerMasterActor (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering block manager hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:56053 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com, 56053) 
2015-04-14 22:41:46,803 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registered BlockManager 
2015-04-14 22:41:55,529 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com:42500/user/Executor#-374031537] with ID 2 
2015-04-14 22:41:55,560 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] util.RackResolver (RackResolver.java:coreResolve(109)) - Resolved hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com to /default-rack 
2015-04-14 22:41:55,653 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com:54112/user/Executor#35135131] with ID 1 
2015-04-14 22:41:55,655 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] util.RackResolver (RackResolver.java:coreResolve(109)) - Resolved hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com to /default-rack 
2015-04-14 22:41:55,690 INFO  [Thread-2] cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8 
2015-04-14 22:41:55,998 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - ensureFreeSpace(298340) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278302556 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,001 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 291.3 KB, free 265.1 MB) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,160 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - ensureFreeSpace(44100) called with curMem=298340, maxMem=278302556 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,161 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 43.1 KB, free 265.1 MB) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,163 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] storage.BlockManagerInfo (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:56053 (size: 43.1 KB, free: 265.4 MB) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,164 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,167 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.DefaultExecutionContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Created broadcast 0 from newAPIHadoopRDD at PythonRDD.scala:516 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,204 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - ensureFreeSpace(298388) called with curMem=342440, maxMem=278302556 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,205 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 291.4 KB, free 264.8 MB) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,279 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - ensureFreeSpace(44100) called with curMem=640828, maxMem=278302556 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,279 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 43.1 KB, free 264.8 MB) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,281 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] storage.BlockManagerInfo (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:56053 (size: 43.1 KB, free: 265.3 MB) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,281 INFO  [Thread-2] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,283 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.DefaultExecutionContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at PythonRDD.scala:497 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,286 INFO  [Thread-2] python.Converter (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Loaded converter: org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,287 INFO  [Thread-2] python.Converter (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Loaded converter: org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,400 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] storage.BlockManagerMasterActor (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering block manager hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com:39033 with 530.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com, 39033) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,434 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] storage.BlockManagerMasterActor (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering block manager hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com:33968 with 530.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com, 33968) 
......
```

Answer (score 0):

```
......
2015-04-14 22:41:56,438 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,438 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:host.name=hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,438 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_75 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,438 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,438 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75.x86_64/jre 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,439 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.class.path=:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-yarn-shuffle.jar:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-shell.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-testing-util-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-it.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2-tests.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/ranger-plugins-common-0.4.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-testing-util.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-shell-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/htrace-core-2.04.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-client.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-examples-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jettison-1.3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-thrift-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/ranger-plugins-cred-0.4.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-prefix-tree.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-it-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/libthrift-0.9.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/ranger-plugins-impl-0.4.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-examples.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-it-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2-tests.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-thrift.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2-tests.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-client-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/ranger-hbase-plugin-0.4.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/ranger-plugins-audit-0.4.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/metrics-core-3.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-sls.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-distcp-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-openstack.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-ant-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041-tests.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/joda-time-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-datajoin.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jetty-6.1.26.hwx.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jetty-util-6.1.26.hwx.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-distcp.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-archives-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-aws-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-sls-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-gridmix-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-rumen-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-datajoin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-archives.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-extras-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-gridmix.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-extras.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-rumen.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-openstack-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/conf:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,439 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,439 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,439 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-04-14 22:41:56,439 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:os.name=Linux 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,440 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:os.arch=amd64 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,440 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,440 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:user.name=root 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,440 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:user.home=/root 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,440 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:user.dir=/root/hbase 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,441 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (ZooKeeper.java:<init>(438)) - Initiating client connection, connectString=hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:2181,hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com:2181,hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=hconnection-0x560cb988, quorum=hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:2181,hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com:2181,hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,458 INFO  [Thread-2] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper (RecoverableZooKeeper.java:<init>(120)) - Process identifier=hconnection-0x560cb988 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:2181,hadoop-node01.mathartsys.com:2181,hadoop-node03.mathartsys.com:2181 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,460 INFO  [Thread-2-SendThread(hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(966)) - Opening socket connection to server hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com/10.0.0.222:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,461 INFO  [Thread-2-SendThread(hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:primeConnection(849)) - Socket connection established to hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com/10.0.0.222:2181, initiating session 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,491 INFO  [Thread-2-SendThread(hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:onConnected(1207)) - Session establishment complete on server hadoop-node02.mathartsys.com/10.0.0.222:2181, sessionid = 0x24cb25197440023, negotiated timeout = 30000 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,605 INFO  [Thread-2] util.RegionSizeCalculator (RegionSizeCalculator.java:<init>(76)) - Calculating region sizes for table "test". 
2015-04-14 22:41:56,984 WARN  [Thread-2] mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase (TableInputFormatBase.java:getSplits(193)) - Cannot resolve the host name for hadoop-node05.mathartsys.com/10.0.0.225 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '225.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa' 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,013 INFO  [Thread-2] spark.DefaultExecutionContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting job: first at SerDeUtil.scala:202 
......
2015-04-14 22:41:57,107 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com, RACK_LOCAL, 1312 bytes) 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,216 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(71)) - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2421) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1382) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

2015-04-14 22:41:57,220 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com, RACK_LOCAL, 1312 bytes) 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,303 INFO  [task-result-getter-1] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on executor hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com: java.lang.IllegalStateException (unread block data) [duplicate 1] 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,306 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com, RACK_LOCAL, 1312 bytes) 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,327 INFO  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on executor hadoop-node04.mathartsys.com: java.lang.IllegalStateException (unread block data) [duplicate 2] 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,330 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com, RACK_LOCAL, 1312 bytes) 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,347 INFO  [task-result-getter-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com: java.lang.IllegalStateException (unread block data) [duplicate 3] 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,348 ERROR [task-result-getter-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logError(75)) - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,350 INFO  [task-result-getter-3] cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,353 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Cancelling stage 0 
2015-04-14 22:41:57,357 INFO  [Thread-2] scheduler.DAGScheduler (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Job 0 failed: first at SerDeUtil.scala:202, took 0.343391 s 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/root/hbase/hbase_test2.py", line 24, in <module>
    conf=conf) 
  File "/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/pyspark/context.py", line 530, in newAPIHadoopRDD 
    jconf, batchSize) 
  File "/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__ 
  File "/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value 
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD. 
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, hadoop-node06.mathartsys.com): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2421) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1382) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

Driver stacktrace: 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696) 
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420) 
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375) 
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) 
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) 
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238) 
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) 
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393) 
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) 
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) 
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) 
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) 

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. 
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 
[root@hadoop-node03 hbase]#
```